# install: you may need to run ldconfig

Tags: installation, readline

I'm trying to install readline-master. The installation steps I've performed are ./configure, make, sudo make install. However, when I execute the last step, I encounter the error 'install: you may need to run ldconfig'. I've already tried entering the command 'sudo ldconfig' but it didn't work.

I'm trying to install readline-master, during the installation step 'make install', I encounter the error 'install: you may need to run ldconfig'.